# jQuery .ajax not working, form posts with page refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post

I have the following html code: (that gets loaded via ajax into a div)

(Cut out the irrelevant parts)

```
<form id='addContactForm' method='post' action='/contact/create/'>
    <div>
        <input type="image" name="submit" id="addContactSubmit" src="/images/add-small.png" style="width: auto; vertical-align: bottom;">
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    $('#addContactSubmit').click(function () {
        alert('got here');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/contact/create/',
            data: $("#addContactForm").serialize(),
            success: function (data, status, xhttp) {
                if (data) {
                    alert('Got Data');
                } else {
                    alert('No Data');
                }
            },
            dataType: html
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

So now when I click on the `<image>`, it actually posts the form and refreshes the page.  I read another post that stated that the problem was that jquery wasn't loaded, and once loaded that fixed the problem.  However, in this case, I am getting the alert, which tells me that jquery is loading (as the click event is triggering fine), however it seems the `$.ajax` portion is not being executed (or there is a problem with it).  If I remove the `$.ajax` portion, I get the alert, and the page does not submit and reload.

Originally I stated that this form html gets loaded via an ajax call on the main page, and I am wondering if that has something to do with the failing ajax post.  Note I also never get the alert ('Got Data') or ('No Data'), only the alert 'got here'

any insite would be great.  Thanks

Another note, I am getting no errors in firebug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a submit input which will automatically post back the form as well as run your ajax script.

Try this...

```
<script>
    $('#addContactSubmit').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('got here');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/contact/create/',
            data: $("#addContactForm").serialize(),
            success: function (data, status, xhttp) {
                if (data) {
                    alert('Got Data');
                } else {
                    alert('No Data');
                }
            },
            dataType: html
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

All I've done is pass the click event to your jQuery function then calling e.preventDefault() stops the execution of the default DOM click event which in this case for a submit button is a post back.

Hope this makes sense, you had it pretty much right!

Comment: that is exactly what I needed! perfect.  I am getting one minor problem though with the above code.  Firebug is showing:
"html is not defined" [Break On This Error] (39 out of range 18).  Now if I remove the 'dataType: html' line it seems to work fine, but is that the best solution?

Comment: have you tried with quotes? so "html". I'm fairly sure without quotes, javascript will think it's a variable, which in this case doesn't exist and is why you'll be getting the Firebug error. You're probably safe leaving that parameter out as when you create the request, jQuery does some internal work and is usually intelligent enough to figure out what data format you are sending. Have a read here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ datatype is about half way down the page